# How do I match several strings in a text using Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to validate a text for several strings that must be present. Say I have the texts

> 1. Rosy made the boys go wild
> 2. Marys wild boys are very crazy indeed
> 3. Henry is a wild boy
> 4. Sally danced with 3 boys last night

And I want to Match the sentences that has both 'boys' AND 'wild' (in any order). The correct matches are 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4.

Anybody?

Comment: Much easier to answer your question if you state what tool you will use for the regexp

Comment: Kirill gave a fine suggestion below, but for the sake of clarity I'm using The RegEx class in ASP.NET/C#...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.*(?=\bboys\b).*(?=\bwild\b)|.*(?=\bwild\b).*(?=\bboys\b)
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

```
/.*?wild.*?boys.*|.*?boys.*?wild.*/
```

You want to use the `.*?` because just `.*` alone is greedy and will consume the entire string. With a greedy match, you'll have no characters left to match against "wild" and "boys" so it will always fail.

Comment: That will find text that contains EITHER, not BOTH.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is overkill here. This works fine and is more readable:

```
for (String str : new String[] { "Rosy made the boys go wild", "Marys wild boys are very crazy indeed",
        "Henry is a wild boy", "Sally danced with 3 boys last night" }) {
    if (str.contains("wild") && str.contains("boys")) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Rosy made the boys go wild
Marys wild boys are very crazy indeed
```

Comment: How do you know that the OP is using Java?

Comment: I agree on your point here. But I need this for a more flexible validation system incl support for more complex regular expression later...

Answer (score 0):

`(^.*boys.*wild.* $|^.*wild.*boys.*$)`

With appropriate escaping depending on where you're using it, of course.